# Custom Form Rendering RegisterTemplateOverrides in a promise issue

Tags: jsom, custom-form, jslink, client-side-rendering, promises

Using custom form rendering with JSLink, I fetch some data in promises before I attempt to do: SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(context);

However because some of the promises takes about 100 ms before it resolves, the form renders by default before moving on with the Promise.then();

So basically the form has been rendered before SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(context); is being called.

What I want to do is to fetch data async before calling SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(context); without triggering the default rendering.

Have someone experienced similar issues?

Comment: After working more with this issue. I see that many who have encountered the same issue have registerred a simple template and then used jquery to override.